Are there any efficient numerical methods to solve the recurrence relation of a function？
First, the recurrence relation is:
$$\pi_{k+1}(\omega)=(\omega-\alpha_k)\pi_{k}(\omega)-\beta_k\pi_{k-1}(\omega),$$
where
$$\alpha_k=\frac{\int_0^\Lambda\omega\pi_{k}^2(\omega)h^2(\omega)\text{d}\omega}{\int_0^\Lambda\pi_{k}^2(\omega)h^2(\omega)\text{d}\omega},\quad \beta_k=\frac{\int_0^\Lambda\pi_{k}^2(\omega)h^2(\omega)\text{d}\omega}{\int_0^\Lambda\pi_{k-1}^2(\omega)h^2(\omega)\text{d}\omega}$$
and its initial condition satisfies:
$$\pi_{k<0}(\omega)=0,\quad \pi_{0}(\omega)=1.$$
I want to know how to efficiently compute as many coefficients $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$ as possible in code. I also wrote a Julia code where $h^2(\omega)\propto\omega/(1+\omega)^2$. However, due to the increase in iterations, the function calls in my code become too deep, causing the computation time for larger $n$ to be very long until the program eventually crashes.
using QuadGK;
# initial parameters
Γ0 = 1e-2;
Λ = 20;

h_squared(ω) = (Γ0 / π^2) * (ω / (1 + ω)^2);

function recursion_coff(πk, pnπk)
    nπk = quadgk(ω -> πk(ω)^2 * h_squared(ω), 0, Λ)[1]
    αk = quadgk(ω -> ω * πk(ω)^2 * h_squared(ω), 0, Λ)[1] / nπk
    βk = nπk / pnπk
    return αk, βk, nπk
end;

N = 60;
em = [];
tm = [];

πkm1 = ω -> 0.0;
πk = ω -> 1.0;
pnπk = 1.0;
for k in 1:N
    αk, βk, pnπk = recursion_coff(πk, pnπk)

    πkp1 = let πk = πk, πkm1 = πkm1, αk = αk, βk = βk
        ω -> (ω - αk) * πk(ω) - βk * πkm1(ω)
    end

    πkm1 = πk
    πk = πkp1

    push!(em, αk)
    push!(tm, βk)
end


You could remove the recursion in the function call entirely by noticing that $\pi_k$ will always be a polynomial and just operate on the coefficients directly.

@whpowell96 I'm sorry. I didn't quite get what you meant. Could you explain it in more detail? Thanks a lot.

Since $\pi_k$ is a polynomial, we can replace the recursion on $\pi_k$ with a recursion on the polynomial coefficients of $\pi_k$. We can even precompute all the integrals since we only need the integrals of $\omega^n h^2(\omega)$. I think this will end up having the same recursion depth as your code, but you will only need to evaluate the recursion once per iteration.  Can you confirm how many times the recursion is being called per iteration in your loop? If the compiler is smart and only does it once, then this method won't provide much speedup

@whpowell96 Thank you very much, this issue has been perfectly resolved. Since there are some special issues (precision) involved, I will write the answer in the reply later.
